# CSS sibling selector not working as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use CSS sibling selectors but seems that they are not working as per rule.

Basically, i am using `panel` from bootstrap and trying to change `panel-heading` css via rules.

I have created a similar markup to replicate the issue and Below is the JS Fiddle link for same

[Link to JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cansjj59/)

I have also tried with below css:

```
.collpase + .heading{
   opacity: 0.2
 }

.collpase.in + .heading{
  opacity: 1
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since one can't select a previous sibling, one can use `flexbox` to achieve that effect by have one order in markup and another visual rendered.

Here I used `flex`, switched order in markup and again, visually, using `flexbox` property `order`

Now both the CSS sibling selectors `~`/`+` will work as they target the next sibling in the markup.

```css
.heading {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.collapse {
  padding: 5px;
  display: none;
  order: 2                      /*  added property  */
}
.collapse.in {
  display: block;
}
.flex {                         /*  added rule */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.collapse ~ .heading {          /*  "collapse" was misspelled  */
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.collapse.in ~ .heading {       /*  "collapse" was misspelled  */
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="firstChild flex">
    <div class="collapse in">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="heading">
      STep 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="secondChild flex">
    <div class="collapse">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="heading">
      STep 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="thirdChild flex">
    <div class="collapse">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="heading">
      STep 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fourthChild flex">
    <div class="collapse">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="heading">
      STep 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For older browsers, `display: table` can be used

```css
.heading {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.collapse {
  padding: 5px;
  display: none;
}
.collapse.in {
  display: table-footer-group;  /*  changed property */
}
.child {                        /*  added rule */
  display: table;
}
.collapse ~ .heading {          /*  "collapse" was misspelled  */
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.collapse.in ~ .heading {       /*  "collapse" was misspelled  */
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first child">
    <div class="collapse in">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="heading">
      STep 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second child">
    <div class="collapse">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="heading">
      STep 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="third child">
    <div class="collapse">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="heading">
      STep 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fourth child">
    <div class="collapse">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="heading">
      STep 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is flex supported in all browsers ?

Comment: @Gags It works in all modern browsers and has a global support around 95%: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox ... Which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: FOr me it still does not work,.. My markup is as in `https://jsfiddle.net/cansjj59/1/`

Comment: @Gags The markup isn't swapped, the class name `collapse` misspelled and the target class is `panel-heading`, not `heading` ... this fiddle work: https://jsfiddle.net/cansjj59/2/

Comment: with above solution .. bootstrap's `<div class="table-responsive">` does not work. Tables are no more reponsive